# Sending extended ASCII character with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to have a shortcut, RAlt+a, that simply sends the right angle quote, «. It is #174 in this table http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-codes-table/ascii-codes-174.html and can be inputted by using Alt+174 when the numlock is on.

I have tried things like

RAlt & a::

Send, {U+0174}

return

and

RAlt & a::

Send, {Asc 0174}

return

but can't get it to work. If there isn't some real easy way, my next plan of action is to determine if Numlock is on, than just input the four keys I need, then turn numlock to it's original state. However, this seems overly complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans,

And this....

```
RAlt & a::Send, {ALTDOWN}{Numpad1}{Numpad7}{Numpad4}{ALTUP}
```

Met vriendelijke groet,

Mit freundlichen Grüßen,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: Hans, I am still puzzled why this does not work on your system, since it works fine on my (Win7) PC: RAlt & a::Send, {ASC 174}

Comment: Thanks very much, Robert. I updated to the latest AHK version, and now the {ASC 174} version works but still not the one with the direct « (still don't know why, but I guess that's okay).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RAlt & a::Send, «
```

Works for me..

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: When I try this I only see boxes. Is it a possible issue in that I have Windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

```
RAlt & a::
theCharacter := chr(174)
Send, %theCharacter%
return
```

This works great for me... However, depending on your computer, you may have issues with the character being sent before your Alt key is released.

Also, you may want to look in to what version of AHK you are running.